# SharePoint Foundation 2013 migration & upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019

Tags: 2019, migration, upgrade-sharepoint, custom-solution

In the migration process when we upgrade the custom solutions from SP 2013 to SP 2019, first we will deploy the custom solutions to SP 2016 and then to 2019. Do we need to upgrade the custom solutions twice to make it compatible for both 2016 and 2019 environments respectively? Or 2016 and 2019 both supports same .Net framework and we will upgrade our solutions only once? Because we would required to open each custom solution source code in Visual Studio and upgrade it for the targeted 2016 or 2019 environment.

The custom solutions upgrade and deployment is the only phase where I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to install custom solutions on your SharePoint 2016 intermediate farm. You will get a bunch of errors during attachment, simply ignore them. All my migrations still worked perfect, as the intermediate-farm is only there to upgrade the DB-Schema from 2013 to 2016.

Comment: Thanks MHeld, this was the answer I was looking for.